# sending an std::wstring from a "chinese Windows" sent to an "arabic Windows"

Tags: windows, unix, unicode, character-encoding, internationalization

I have a socket through which I sent serialized std::wstring, so for example let's say, from an chinese version of Windows to an Unix system working with Arabic UI.

I can't understand how my Unix system (or anything else) will know that these std::wstring are chinese one's, I don't see that "code page" (aka country language ?) is stored in std::wstring, do I have to associate myself the code page of potentially each std::wstring ?

I miss something for sure as this looks as a basic question in our interconnected world  ...

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `wstring` is to allow the entire Unicode character set, which includes Chinese and Arabic and every other character set known to man. It almost completely obsoletes the concept of a code page - the characters have the same representation on a computer based in any language.

See [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for starters.

You might run into some trouble with the transfer, as `wchar_t` will typically be 16 bits on Windows and 32 bits on Linux. There also might be some big-endian vs. little-endian issues to worry about. The safest course of action is to transfer via UTF-8, which encodes the Unicode characters into sequences of 8-bit bytes which are unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, `wstring` is encoded as a unicode encodings, which are language neutral. No matter what language settings you're using on your own computer, the content of the `wstring` is the same (this is one of the main advantages of Unicode!).

However, note that there is more than one Unicode encoding, and Unix platforms often use a different one from Windows (UCS-32 vs UTF-16). I would recommend converting explicitly to UTF-8 for transfer between machines; on Windows use [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (with `CP_UTF8`), and on unixen use [`iconv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/iconv.html) to convert between your local `wstring` encoding and UTF-8 (on Unix, it's more common to simply use UTF-8 everywhere, note - in that case you'd use a normal `std::string` with UTF-8 text in it on the Unix side).